# Grignard reaction - exchange of groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity, reaction-control

Why is this reaction successful:
[image]

Why doesn't metal-halide exchange occur easily to get Ar-MgCl and R-Br?

Comment: Why do you think it should? Could you elaborate?

Comment: A similar reaction is used in the synthesis of  sibutramine, only the aldehyde is replaced with a cyanide group, and R=isobutyl.

Comment: I guess the reason is that metal halide exchange is *very fast* only in the case of _lithium organyls_ while it proceeds slower for grignard reagents.

Comment: And I guess that chlorine isn't that susceptible, while Br and I would be.